# Angular 17 @switch multiple values in case

Tags: angular

I have angular 17 and i'm using control flow.
I want to use @switch

Example:

```
@switch (variable) {
   @case ("sun")
   {
     //do something
   }
   @case ("sea")
   { 
   }
}
```

Now i have two different value of variable but do same things, how can i do that? It is possible something like this? :

```
 @switch (variable) {
   @case ("sun","moon")
   {
     //do something
   }
   @case ("sea")
   { 
   }
}
```

Solution or suggestions

Comment: Did you try to use the syntax of Angular template? That would be `@case ("sun" || "moon")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give the `switch` as `true` the indivual cases can be rewritten with javascript array method `.includes` to check for multiple values, this will achieve what you want!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="value"/>
    @switch (true) {
      @case (["sun","moon"].includes(this.value))
      {
        <h1>sun or moon</h1>
      }
      @case (this.value === "sea")
      { 
     <h1>sea</h1>
      }
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  value = 'moon';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ged9ab?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)